# predict value of a New Product based on others?

Tags: python, excel, prediction

I have the following dataset, Each row is a car with 5 Values, and in the end his price

I will like to add a new car row with the 5 values, and get the Price calculated/predicted based on the learned from the previous rows.

Can this be done in excel or python?

[image: car values]

Comment: It can be done with any language and Excel. You need to explain what is the prediction algorithm - how the price is calculated based in Value1,Value2...

Comment: that's what I dont know. I have a large dataset with this values, i need a formula that predicts that final value for new entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a method to solve a 'regression' problem. There are lots of ways to do this in both Python and Excel. You will find a lot of help on how to set up your data if you google 'Python regression Machine Learning'.

For Python I would try using the scikit-learn module. A sample code might look like this:

```py
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd

# assume the input dataset you have above is read into a pandas dataframe:
data = pd.read_csv('inputdata.csv')

X = data[['Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5']]
y = data['Price']
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X, y)

# now assuming some new set of data with the same columns as your training data 
X_test = pd.read_csv('inputdata.csv')[['Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5']]

# can generate predictions with
predictions = regr.predict(X_test)
```

You can see from the above that the code to make some kind of model which will make predictions of a new value is very small. However the model may not do a very good job. To understand how to build a strong model is beyond the scope of this question, but there are many resources online to help you do this, [for example](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-using-python-ce21aa90ade6).

Comment: Works ok, but how do I enter a new record to predict the price if a provide the first 5 values ?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at examples of how to use pandas to make dataframes in Python if you are not familiar. e.g. [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dataframe_examples/)

You can input a dataframe with the same columns, but different rows into the regr.predict(X) method. I have edited the answer to make this clearer